# Android AVD - Home is defined but not find nexus6.xml in $HOME

Tags: android, sdk, emulation

I've got everything working for cordova but I was playing with Library/Android/sdk/tools/android avd

and I deleted an Android Virtual Devices from the list. Then created another one. I don't think this is related as you can create as many as you like. However now I'm getting this error when I,

```
sudo cordova emulate android
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

```
Total time: 11.64 secs
Built the following apk(s): 
/Users/UserName/Documents/app-dev/giraffebuilder/hollywood-and-me/hello/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
 ANDROID_HOME=/Users/UserName/Library/Android/sdk
 JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home
 No emulator specified, defaulting to nexus6
 Waiting for emulator to start...
 **PANIC: Unknown AVD name [nexus6], use -list-avds to see valid list.
 HOME is defined but could not find nexus6.ini file in $HOME/.android/avd
 (Note: avd is searched in the order of         $ANDROID_AVD_HOME,$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd and $HOME/.android/avd)**
```

when I run

```
 sudo cordova requirements
```

Everything is good!

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-3,android-4,android-5,android-6,android-     7,android-8,android-9,android-10,android-11,android-12,android-13,android-   14,android-15,android-16,android-17,android-18,android-19,android-20,android-21,android-22,android-23,android-24,android-25, 
Google Inc.:Google APIs:15,Google Inc.:Google APIs:16,Google Inc.:Google APIs:17,Google Inc.:Google APIs:18,Google Inc.:Glass Development 
Kit Preview:19,Google Inc.:Google APIs:19,Google Inc.:Google APIs:21,
Google Inc.:Google APIs:22,Google Inc.:Google APIs:23,Google Inc.:Google APIs:24

Gradle: installed

Requirements check results for ios:
Apple OS X: installed darwin
Xcode: installed 8.1
ios-deploy: installed 1.9.0
CocoaPods: installed
```

Can you guys please help me trouble shoot this, what am I doing wrong here?